# When is LIN used over I2C?

Tags: i2c, communication, can, lin

I am doing research about some communication protocols: CAN, LIN, I2C, and how they're used mainly in the automotive industry but I'm getting confused as to when each of them are used and if their use cases overlap.

I understand when CAN is used over LIN: LIN is lower cost, less reliable, only uses one wire, is slower, and is time triggered; but I am not able to understand when you would use LIN over I2C since they're quite similar from my point of view. I guess there is a fundamental difference I'm not seeing but don't know what it is.

Comment: LIN is basically used where a car manufacturer ought to be using CAN but they decided to cheap out on the electronics, it's a "poor man's CAN". Typically it is used in non-safety related parts like controlling car windows, mirrors etc. I don't think it is used much at all outside car electronics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with LIN (I just did a quick research), but there are several significant differences :

- LIN is single wire (not counting ground and power supply) vs 2 wires for I2C, which is a significant gain in space/cost/reliability wen you get as many components as in a modern car.
- I2C is the short for "inter-integrated circuit", and it's really what it is meant for : to communicate between integrated circuits (situated on the same PCB) and not to communicate between different PCBs/devices. For PCBs that are really close, it might still work (at least for "normal" applications, not sure for automotive were you get a quite noise environment). But usually, when exceeding a few tens of centimeters, you start getting communication errors. So wiring a component at the other end of the car is out of question. On the other hand, LIN is [up to 40m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network), so better suited for wiring around the whole car (or event truck)
- I2C is a "general purpose" protocol, that is very used in the electronics industry, so many components are available for small prices. LIN seems to be rather specific to the automotive industy.

So I would say :

- for a PCB to communicate with another one in the car : LIN (or CAN)
- for communication within the same PCB : I2C

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick synopsis, there are books on each subject. You can use google and enter the first 3 letters in your search bar and get thousands of responses. Each one was originally designed to solve a specific problem but has since expanded to cover a much broader area. The one chosen is a tradeoff that the designer has to make.

I2C (Inter-Integrated Circuit) is a bus interface connection protocol incorporated into devices for serial communication. It was originally  designed for communication on PCBs, not as a bus that connects to off board devices. To the best of my knowledge there is no I2C bus in cars, usage on boards is excepted.

LIN  (Local Interconnect Network) is a single wire, serial network used for communication between components in vehicles. Because of its single-wire architecture is more susceptible to electromagnetic interference than two-wire buses. The recommended data rate is limited to 20 kb/s and a maximum of 16 nodes.

The previous two need chassis ground to work properly in automotive as it is the return path.

CAN (Controlled Area Network) Is a 2 wire multi master very robust network. Basically it is a message-based protocol designed to allow the Electronic Control Units (ECUs) found in today's vehicles. Can is used in many applications beyond automotive.